# Android Fragment instance variable vs Bundle arguments?

Tags: android-fragments, bundle, android-bundle

What is the difference between Android Fragment instance variables and the bundle arguments?
When to use what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Bundle` is sort of presistent data. The Android runtime may restart you `Activity` or `Fragment` for example on orientation changes of your device. The variables of your first instance (let's say the one used in portrait layout) are not present when Android creates a second instance that it will use for the landscape layout.

By placing state/variables in the `Bundle` the new instance of your class gets back the variables, when it's recreated.

You can add the instance variables you want to keep to the `Bundle` in the `onSaveInstanceState()` method of the first instance. When the second instance is created, you get these in the `Bundle` that is passed to your `onCreate()` method.